# How to make a Custom Post Type entry to have different parent pages

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I have a Custom Post Type "press-releases"

I want to be able to setup different parent pages for each entry from this CPT.

Example, I want to have something like:

website.com/parent-page/one-cpt-entry

website.com/another-parent-page/other-entry-from-this-same-cpt

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your custom post type to support parents and children by setting [the `hierarchical` argument on `register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#hierarchical) to `true`.

If you're wanting to have posts from your CPT be children of posts of the `page` post type, that is not possible, at least not without introducing instability.